# Looking for a clean way to implement time deltas (python)?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I am writing a function to time stamp a given message (message_ts) in the format `updated x {hours/days/months} ago`. Specifically, I am trying to time stamp the message with the most "meaningful" units (i.e. `Updated 5 hours ago` is much more helpful than `updated .xxxx years ago`) Below is my attempt at a "clean" implementation, but I'm convinced that a more elegant  soln exists (perhaps a 1 liner??). These constants (3600, 86400, ...) are the number of seconds per unit. Thanks.

```
delta = int((datetime.utcnow() - message_ts).total_seconds())

if (hours := delta//3600) < 24:       return f'updated {hours} hour{"s"*(hours!=1)} ago'
elif (days := delta//86400) < 7:      return f'updated {days} day{"s"*(days!=1)} ago'
elif (weeks := delta//604800) < 5:    return f'updated {weeks} week{"s"*(weeks!=1)} ago'
elif (months := delta//2592000) < 12: return f'updated {months} month{"s"*(months!=1)} ago'
else:                                 return 'Updated more than 1 year ago'
```

Comment: You'll get better answers asking this on the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Note that everything greater than a week is not unambiguous anymore - a month can have 28 to 31 days etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library to do this: [timeago](https://pypi.org/project/timeago/)

Here is an example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import timeago

message_ts = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)
print(timeago.format(message_ts, datetime.now()))  # will print 1 day ago

message_ts = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=48)
print(timeago.format(message_ts, datetime.now()))  # will print 2 days ago

message_ts = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=2)
print(timeago.format(message_ts, datetime.now()))  # will print 2 hours ago

message_ts = datetime.now() - timedelta(weeks=2)
print(timeago.format(message_ts, datetime.now()))  # will print 2 weeks ago

message_ts = datetime.now() - timedelta(weeks=5)
print(timeago.format(message_ts, datetime.now()))  # will print 1 month ago
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have `IPython` installed in your environment, I like the way they display the timing results (for `%%time` and `%timeit`):

```py
from IPython.core.magics.execution import _format_time as pretty_timedelta

>>> pretty_timedelta(93*24*3600 + 3745.123456)
'93d 1h 2min 25s'

>>> pretty_timedelta(1.123456)
'1.12 s'

>>> pretty_timedelta(0.000123)
'123 µs'
```

It doesn't have weeks as a unit, but you can easily take the code and derive your own function with this extra unit.

For 'month', 'quarter', 'year', etc., remember that those are not fixed time delta, but instead relative offsets. So you cannot know how many months are e.g. `40 * 24 * 3600` seconds, because months can be anything around 30 days.